# Terminal input gives null pointer but IDE input runs fine

Tags: java, arraylist, file-io

Trying to build a program that changes stuff in SRC folder.  for (File f : files) {    Returns a null pointer despite returning appropriate answer in Intellij IDE. This program searches my SRC file directory and lists all files pertaining to the the directory. It works fine in the IDE but does not do the correct function on the command line.

```
//This program is from Liang Comprehensive Java 12.18

import java.io.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class AddStatement {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
   // File dir = new File(args[0]);
    File dir=new File("src");
    System.out.println(dir.getCanonicalPath() + " Was put into console");
    writeTofile(getfiles(dir));

  }//End of main class

 public static ArrayList<String> getfiles(File dirc) throws IOException {
    ArrayList<String> paths = new ArrayList<String>(5);
    File[] files = dirc.listFiles();

   for (File f : files) {         //This part is where null is happening                  
       paths.add(f.getCanonicalPath());

    }//End of foreach
    return paths;
 }//End of getFiles method


 public static void writeTofile(ArrayList<String> files) throws IOException {
    String file;
    int count = 1;
    for (String f : files) {
        file = f;
        try (PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(file, true))) {
            if (file.contains("Chapter")) {
                writer.print("\\\\Chapter" + count);
                count++;
            }//End of filtering if
        }//End of try block

    }//End of for loop
    System.out.println("Files written");
 }//End writeTofile


}// End of Class
```

Comment: first guess will be that you start your program in a directory where **src** directory is missing.

Comment: From the Javadoc of [`File.listFiles()`](https://download.java.net/java/GA/jdk14/docs/api/java.base/java/io/File.html#listFiles%28%29) : **returns**: [...] Returns `null` if this abstract pathname does not denote a directory, or if an I/O error occurs.

Comment: @ Khun. This makes sense, but, it works in the IDE. Does an IDE change how a computer sees a directory?

Comment: @kofeman, thats impossible, using Intellij Idea's terminal interface, you get put directly into the directory in question.

Comment: well, that add isExist() and isDirectory() to proof that.

Comment: Yep, something is up. Came back with false() on the terminal, but true on the IDE. Must be a bug with one of the systems.